# Most efficient way of querying sites by a parameter in their url

Tags: url, site, query, web, parameter

What's the most efficient way of retrieving ALL SPWeb (root and sub) in a SPWebApplication? Only SPWeb whose url contains a given string as a Url parameter should be retrieved.

For example:

I have 5 sites:

```
http://server.com:555/                            <---- should not be retrieved
http://server.com:555/sites/getthis               <---- should be retrieved
http://server.com:555/sites/root1/getthis/        <---- should be retrieved
http://server.com:555/sites/root2/dontgetthis/    <---- should not be retrieved
http://server.com:555/sites/root3/getthis/        <---- should be retrieved
```

I should query all SPWebs who have the url parameter "getthis" and nothing else.

So what is the most efficient way of doing this? (C#)

Comment: .net or powershell?

Comment: c# specifically, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check if the site / subsite URL contains a specific value  , I wrote this code in my side that working properly :

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://Qassasrootsite/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                        //Get the sites / sub site 
                        string sitelist = "";
                        foreach (SPWeb spWeb in site.AllWebs)
                        {
                        if (spWeb.Url.ToString().Contains("Qassas"))
                          {
                            sitelist += "," + spWeb.Url.ToString();
                          }
                        }    
                }
            }
```

The above solution will work as your above request (**Contains**) , but it will retrieve all the URL's that contains your provided value (not depend on where it find the provided value in the URL).

**For example**, you need to find the URL with `qassas` keyword

```
http://rootsite/qassas  should be retrieved
http://rootsite/qassas/wiki  should be retrieved
```

Meanwhile, if you need to check the last part in URL to check if it's equal the provided value or not try to split your URL as the following

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://Qassasrootsite/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                        //Get the sites / sub site 
                        string sitelist = "";
                        foreach (SPWeb spWeb in site.AllWebs)
                        {
                            var siteurl = spWeb.Url.ToString().Split('/');
                            // get the last item in site uel array that contains the site name
                            if (siteurl[siteurl.Length - 1].ToString() == "Qassas")
                            {
                                sitelist += "," + spWeb.Url.ToString();
                            }
                        }    
                }
            }
```

**For example,** you need to find the URL with `qassas` keyword

```
http://rootsite/qassas  should be retrieved
http://rootsite/qassas/wiki  should not be retrieved
```

Now you have the two code sample, you can select that match your requirements :)

Comment: I already knew that you could iterate through sites and webs. But I thought that maybe there was a more efficient way as this essentially retrieves all webs before determining whether those webs actually satisfy given parameters.

Comment: Hi @LeonidasFett , you didn't mention in your question that you knew this  !!!! No problem, I only tried to help you , but I would like to tell you that any comparison criteria based on a specific value will require a looping specifically in your case, you tried to check if all site URL have a specific value or not so you should loop for all sites list, where i introduced a two method with contain function or with last part in your URL.so it should be efficient way because it achieve your target meanwhile it dispose the web and site object ,  Hope to find another efficient way,Good Luck!

Comment: no problem dude. I wasn't bummed or anything. :)